# React, Conditionally send props to Component

Tags: reactjs

```
const Comp = ({noValue, value}) => (
  <Slider value={value}>
)
```

Is there any way to not send the `value-property` based on a condition (noValue)?

So if `noValue = true: < Slider />`

if `noValue = false: < Slider value={value} />`

`<Slider />` is an external lib and it crashes if I do `value={null}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Above answers are good too, just wanted to show some alternate syntax

```
const Comp = ({noValue, value}) => {
  const props = noValue ? {} : {value: value};
  return <Slider {...props}>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `undefined` as the `value` prop if `noValue` is true.

```
const Comp = ({ noValue, value }) => (
  <Slider value={noValue ? undefined : value} />
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way

```
  const Comp = ({noValue, value}) => (
     <Slider value={noValue ? null : value} />
  )
```

Or

```
const Comp = ({noValue, value}) => {
     if(noValue){
        return <Slider />
     }
     return <Slider value={value}>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows:

```
const Comp = ({value}) => (
    value ?
   <Slider value={value}> 
   :
   <Slider />
)
```

This should help.